# Bryant 355 furnace not heating

Tags: furnace

My furnace runs and trips roll out without blowing warm air, I suspect the inducer isn't running fast enough.  I watch it kick on and the inducer runs fast but right when it lights the inducer slows down and the flame starts rolling out.

Comment: By "rolling out" you mean that the flame goes out? Just confirming because that's not an expression I've heard used before.

Comment: The flame is not being pulled sufficiently enough and the box that contains the burners is getting very hot and the flame roll out sensor is tripping and shutting down the furnace